# How to use SQL Server Compact Edition 32bits on Windows 64bit?

Tags: c#, .net, x86, 64-bit, sql-server-ce

I'm actually using SQL CE for my C# .NET application and so far I didn't have any issues with it.

But recently I had to pass my AnyCpu compiled application to a 32-bit only compilation (due to a DLL only available in x86). But now, DbProviderFactories doesn't find anymore SQL CE and throw an exception that explain I might not have it installed on my computer (Win 7 64-bits).

I guess it's because he wants to link on the SQL CE 32-bit version instead of the 64-bits installed version. But when I try to install the 32-bit version of SQL CE, the installer tells me as I'm on a 64-bit OS, I must use the 64-bits installer...

Does anyone had this issue by willing using a 32-bit application using SQL CE on a 64-bit OS? Is there any solution?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to use CE today? It's discontinued - you should use Express or LocalDB.

Comment: On a x64 system, both the x860and x64 runtimes are always present, easiest solution is to always compile to x86..

Comment: @AaronBertrand Because all our products/code today are deployed/using SQL CE. Migration of client deployed/functioning technology is not our priority right now.

Comment: @ErikEJ Are your sure both are deployed and available? Why my DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0") is launching exception then?

Comment: Because your machine.config entries are missing, repair/reinstall both msi,s

Comment: @ErikEJ Arg! The DbProvider was missing in machine.config, I should have look a it first.. Thanks! If you reply with your response, i'll check it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required DbProvider entries are missing from machine.config, reinstall both the runtime MSIs to fix.